# How can I run more then too commands with WScript.Shell object?

Tags: vba, batch-file, cmd

I'm using below macro in goal of obtaining list of all files in folder :

```
Sub SO()

Const parentFolder As String = "C:\Users\bloggsj\folder\" '// change as required, keep trailing slash

Dim results As String

results = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & parentFolder & "*.*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll

Debug.Print results

Ens Sub
```

but it gives me invalid output as it doesn't chandle Unicode characters, which are part of files names in my directory. In normal batch file I could use additional command 'CHCP 1250' to change coding page for symbols. But I can't incorpotrate it into above macro. I've tried in several ways like :

```
results = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C CHCP 1250 DIR """ & parentFolder & "*.*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll
```

and

```
results = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C ""CHCP 1250"" ""DIR """ & parentFolder & "*.*"" /S /B /A:-D""").StdOut.ReadAll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ampersand**

> command1 & command2 : Use to separate multiple commands on one command
>   line. Cmd.exe runs the first command, and then the second command.

```
CMD /C CHCP 1250 & DIR ....
```

However VBA has [native support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba) for a directory listing and VBScript can use the `FileSystemObject` to achieve the same.

Comment: `FileSystemObject` is too slow